# how to set the image for the links in dnn

Tags: dotnetnuke

we need to set the page links as image in the DotNetNuke(dnn), mean the home page link should be image not text and contact us separate image, about us separate image, and the drop down are to be separate images, how i can do this?

DotNetNuke.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way through the UI in DNN to do this, but if you are creating a custom skin and using the DNNMenu skin object you can target the specific items in the navigate with a CSS class, doing this would allow you to change each menu item with an image.

For example for the "HOME" link on my website (www.chrishammond.com) I could provide CSS like .id36{background-image:url('http://www/someimage.jpg');} though I would also want to be sure to hide the text, and provide a height/width